# Java input: Scanner or IOException

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, ioexception

I am taking a Java class at school and the teacher states that I should use an instance of the `Scanner` class to read input from the console.

Example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Public class ExampleName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);            
        char letter;

        letter = input.next().charAt(0);
    }
}
```

However, I read [Java: A Beginner's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071809252) over the summer and throughout the book it said to use `System.in.read()` to read input.

Example:

```
import java.io.IOException;

Public class ExampleChar {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        char letter;

        letter = (char) System.in.read();
    }
}
```

Which form is correct? Which form should I use for getting basic input (char, int, double, etc....)?

Comment: Both are different ways. The first one is the most used as far as I know.

Comment: I agree with @Christian - This is the most common way I have seen as well. The other advantage is that you then have a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#method_summary) object that you can now perform additional functionality with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you notice, in your example, that when initialising the `Scanner` you pass it `System.in`?

`System.in` returns instance of an `InputStream` (since JDK1.0)

> The "standard" input stream. This stream is already open and ready to supply input data. Typically this stream corresponds to keyboard input or another input source specified by the host environment or user.

The `Scanner` (since JDK1.5) uses the `InputStream` from `System.in` and parses the `InputStream` using regular expressions, thus providing easier access to the data contain in `System.in`

> Scanner(System.in) Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified input stream. Bytes from the stream are converted into characters using the underlying platform's default charset.

I would suggest using `Scanner`, it makes code cleaner and easier to maintain by providing methods like:

`next()` - returns next `String`

`nextInt()` - returns next `int`

`nextDouble()` - returns next `double`

`next(Pattern pattern)` - returns next String matching `pattern`

Comment: I did not know about how InputStream related to Scanner and System.in, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid ways to get input from the console.

Using the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) can make things a bit easier, since it provides more methods you can use to retrieve input, such as `nextFloat` and `nextInt` and also methods such as `hasNextDouble` that can be used to verify the input.

The [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) (`System.in`) is more limited in functionality and only provide a few `read` methods, meaning it might require extra manual work.

To read standard input from the console (such as doubles, ints, etc) I would use the `new Scanner(System.in)` approach. Use the one that makes most sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` and `System.in.read()` are different ways to read the input from Java code but the result is the same, it depends on programmer choice what one should use.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answers I want to say that, you can use the following methods -

- `nextInt()` - for reading `integer`
- `nextDouble()` - for reading `double`
- `nextByte()` - for reading `byte`
- `nextLong()` - for reading `long` and so on...

And here the `next()` method you have added - is used to read any `token` as a whole.

More detail can be found from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) of `Scanner`.